# MarginTop работает для TextView в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой TextView лежит внутри ConstraintLayout и MarginTop не работает для верхней границы. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полная структура:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:title="@string/title_about"
        app:titleMarginStart="62dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_body"
                style="@style/Body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.

По своей сути рыбатекст является альтернативой традиционному lorem ipsum, который вызывает у некторых людей недоумение при попытках прочитать рыбу текст. В отличии от lorem ipsum, текст рыба на русском языке наполнит любой макет непонятным смыслом и придаст неповторимый колорит советских времен."/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите полный код

Comment: видимо компоновка сверстана так, что на этот маржин не хватает места. С ConstrainLayout такое бывает.

Comment: Покажите как у вас `TextView ` в `ConstraintLayout ` расположен. Возможно он не имеет привязки своего верха в родителю, вот и не приненён отступ

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил код

Comment: @Timur Mukhortov добавил код

Answer (score 1):

Нужно подключить TextView к границам родителя. Сделать это можно добавив в TextView:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Подробности по ссылке: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Margins

Comment: не только top, тут все четыре стороны не прикреплены

Comment: @pavlofff,  да. Но margin'ы для Left и Right работают и без прикрепления.

Comment: @EgorChetvernin, скорее всего работают левый и правый, т.к. вьюха на весь контейнер по ширине. Если высоту такой же сделать, то, видать, и сверху/снизу заработают)

Comment: @EgorChetvernin прикреплять все равно надо, не стоит бросать виджет в "подвешенном" состоянии